# Securing Cloud Functions using IAM + NodeJS application running on AppEngine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I need some help with example if possible of code changes to be done on my NodeJS server code running on AppEngine in order to allow it to securely access my cloud fucntions.

I created a cloud function and I have a public URL for it. I then went ahead and removed `allUser` access in the `Permissions' tab of the function. Under Service account I have` App Engine Default Service account` selected.

My server on AppEngine was calling the public URL of the CF and when `allUser' permission was there, everything was hunky dory. But when it was removed, I started getting 403 error.

I need help with code changes on NodeJS side to be able to invoke the cloud fucntion again please.
My CF and App engine are in the same project and in the same region.

My server code is as follows using an https library to make the post request.

```
    const checkingData = JSON.stringify({
      'check' : 123
    })
    const checkingOptions = {
      hostname: MY_CLOUD_PUBLIC_URL,
      port: 443,
      timeout: 5000,
      path: MY_CLOUD_URL_PATH,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': checkingData.length,
      }
    }
    const checkRequest = https.request(checkingOptions, checkD => {
      if (checkD.statusCode==200) { // OK?
        checkD.on('data', d => {
          // Do something useful with the data
        })
   })
   checkRequest.write(checkingData);
   checkRequest.end();
```

I have been trying to find an answer for this for days now and started having migranes because of this. Any help with example code would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

---

**EDIT**

I can see the token now! (Yayyy!)

I changed my `checkingOptions` to work with request-promise in the following way:

```
const checkingOptions = {
    uri: 'https://'+process.env.CLOUD_URL+process.env.CHECK,
    port: 443,
    timeout: 5000,
    body:checkingData,
    json: true,
//    path: process.env.CHECK,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': checkingData.length,
    }
  }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 401 - "\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<title>401 Unauthorized</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/check</code>.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n"
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at new StatusCodeError (/workspace/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at Request.plumbing.callback (/workspace/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/workspace/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at Request.self.callback (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at Request.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
2021-02-27 19:38:01 default[20210227t192944]      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
```

**Do I need a middleware in my cloud function as well? My cloud function looks like the follow:**

```
exports.check = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('----CHECKING----');
  res.status(200).send('Hello from checking');
})
```

IAM ROLES:
[image]

CLOUD FUNCTION > PERMISSIONS TAB

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a great example in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#nodejs). If you want I adapt it to your code, it could look like to this

```
// Make sure to `npm install --save request-promise` or add the dependency to your package.json
const request = require('request-promise');

// Set up metadata server request
// See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature
const metadataServerTokenURL = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';
const tokenRequestOptions = {
    uri: metadataServerTokenURL + MY_CLOUD_PUBLIC_URL,
    headers: {
        'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
    }
};


const checkingData = JSON.stringify({
  'check' : 123
})
const checkingOptions = {
  uri: MY_CLOUD_PUBLIC_URL, //!!!changed here!!!
  port: 443,
  timeout: 5000,
  path: MY_CLOUD_URL_PATH,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': checkingData.length,
  }
}

request(tokenRequestOptions).then((token) => {
   request(checkingOptions).auth(null, null, true, token).then((response) => { //!!!changed here!!!
       checkD.on('data', d => {
         // Do something useful with the data
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }); => {
  
})

checkRequest.write(checkingData);
checkRequest.end();
```

Don't forget to add the role `role/cloudfunctions.invoker` to the App Engine default service account, either at the project level or at the Cloud Functions level.

---

**EDIT 1**

Correct. `request-promise` has been deprecated for year. What alternative? I absolutely don't know because NodeJS hurts me (as I said in the comment).

As a lazy man, I found an alternative. I found the `request-promise` in the Cloud Run documentation. But you have to know that Cloud Run and Cloud Functions are very closed (they share the same underlying platform). I take my chance with [Cloud Functions authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function) and bingo! There is an example with `node-fetch`

```
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    const MY_CLOUD_PUBLIC_URL = '....'
    const metadataServerTokenURL = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';

    // Fetch the token
    const tokenResponse = await fetch(metadataServerTokenURL + MY_CLOUD_PUBLIC_URL, {
        headers: {
            'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google',
        },
    });
    const token = await tokenResponse.text();
    console.log(token)

    const checkingData = JSON.stringify({
        'check' : 123
    })

    // Provide the token in the request to the receiving function
    try {
        const functionResponse = await fetch(MY_CLOUD_PUBLIC_URL, {
            method: 'post',
            body:    checkingData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `bearer ${token}`},
        });
        console.log(await functionResponse.text());
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
```

Add your check functions and it should work now!

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with my comments and console log.

Comment: I just noticed that there is no mention of my checkingOptions and my https request in above code. Where will that be placed please?

Comment: My bad, I forgot this. I updated the piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I now get the error on line 57 i.e. `request(tokenRequestOptions).then((token) ` as `TypeError: request(...).then is not a function
2021-02-24 13:41:50 default[20210224t134017]      at /workspace/app.js:57:32....`. Also don't see `checkRequest.write(checkingData);
checkRequest.end()` being used. Where do you add checkingData?

Comment: Anyone? Please I need help. Do I need to register anywhere with google to make this code run?

Comment: request-promise seems deprecated. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: I finally tested (and it hurt me because I'm bad in nodeJS) and I updated my code in the answer. I noted the changes in comment at the end of the line. I logged the token and the response and both worked as expected!

Comment: I found an alternative with node-fetch. Let me know if better

Comment: Big Thanks! I have updated the question with the problem. Very pleased to report the progress as well.

Comment: 401 -> your current service account isn't authorized to access the cloud functions. Grant it and it should be ok

Comment: I re-checked after your comment above - I have my `App Engine Default Account` set as `Cloud Function Invoker` in BOTH `IAM `& inside `CloudFunction>Permissions` tab. Is there any place I have missed? (Updated my question with more details as well)

Comment: Work like a charm on App Engine on my side with the latest version of my code

Comment: Any suspects? I feel so close to achieving this.  I have added screenshots of both IAM and Permissions tab for your reference.

Comment: No... I made a type in the body part of the code example (a J before checkingData).

Comment: that's fine, I knew it is just a typo. I took care of it. It has to be something else.

Comment: So. I managed to make small change and getting 302 error. 1) I split the `path` and the `URI` to seperate variables in `checkingOptions`. 2) I added `https://` in front of my my cloud url i.e. `uri: metadataServerTokenURL + 'https://' + MY_CLOUD_PUBLIC_URL`